# Fantasy book about an assassin turned investigator

Tags: story-identification

I'm currently trying to find out what a book I read about 10-20 years ago was named. I would like to find out the title in order to read it again sometime in the near future!

It played in a fantasy world (Forgotten Realms even?) and started in a city at the edge of the civilized world.  What I remember for sure are the following parts:

- An assassin was hired and tried to kill a man clad in heavy armor.
- The man beat him but let him live.
- The assassin wanted now to find out who hired him in order to give the money he had taken for the job back, as he was unable to fullfill it.
- A murder happened, and the assassin and the armored guy were at first thought to be the perpetrators; but they managed to get the city officials to let them handle the investigation instead and find out who did the murderer.
- The city itself found itself surrounded by a barbarian horde... with the murdered one being a very high ranked guy from said horde. They wanted answers or they would destroy the city.
- The guy in the armor was the fists of the team, while the assassin brought the intelligence.
- The armoured guy couldn't take off the armour (it was made out of a young dragons scales... and its mother was still searching its murderer) as it was cursed. He only wanted to find a way to take it off.

I also remember that one part of the city had shipwreck-like housings. Then that the assassin and the armoured guy were in some sort of cell in the ground once, and that the whole ordeal with the barbarian horde, the murderer and the assassins job all had to do with the armoured guy in the end. And that at the end of the novel... the mother dragon came there to take her revenge. (The assassin and the warrior survived, but the perpetrator was hidden among the barbarians and was the warrior's old friend, the very same friend who left him to die when he took on the young dragon years back.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the book. It was not as I had thought Forgotten Realms, but a Dragonlance book.

It's english title was "Murder in Tarsis" published in 1996.

Wikipedia Text (copied from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_in_Tarsis )

> This novel is about Tarsis, a once proud city by the sea, now
>   landlocked and decaying because of a great catastrophe, with a huge
>   nomad army laying siege to its crumbling walls; and the main character
>   is Ironwood – a mercenary bearing the curse of the dragon he once slew.

Comment: Congratulations! You can accept your own answer, as I'm sure you know, having all those gold badges. :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I know tnx although I dislike answering it on my own. more than accidently stumbled upon the correct book entry in wikipedia at long last.